# What is the origin of the study of compactifications using lattices?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, math-history, lattice-orders, compactification

Lately, I've been really interested in compactifications of topological spaces, so I've started reading research papers about it. In the literature, I've found a very interesting idea, which is to order the distinct compactifications of a given space $X$ using partial orders, and (eventually) get a lattice.

It works like this: given two compactifications $\alpha_1 X$ and $\alpha_2 X$ of a noncompact topological space $X$, we define a relation $\alpha_1 X \preceq \alpha_2 X$ iff there exists a surjective continuous function $f: \alpha_2 X \to \alpha_1 X$ that leaves $X$ pointwise fixed (i.e. $f(x) = x$ for every $x \in X$). It turns out that in certain spaces $X$ (for example, when $X$ is locally compact) the relation $\preceq$ induces a lattice of **lattice of compactifications of $X$**.

I traced back this idea following the references of the first papers I found talking about this, the references in the references, etc., and I eventually found some papers dating back to the 1960s - 1970s: "The lattice of compactifications of a locally compact space" (Magill Jr., 1966), "On Hausdorff compactifications" (Rayburn, 1973), "Lattices of compactifications of Tychonoff spaces" (Ünlü, 1977), etc. However, all of them assume this idea as a well known thing.

I would like to know who came up with this idea, and what are the first papers/articles/books that talk about it (ideally I'd love to know the original one).

Comment: I have some suggestions for this question, possible improvements that might make it a candidate for re-opening. You say that you found this idea in the literature. Can you bring the question into better focus by explaining the mathematical definition of this partial ordering? Can you cite where exactly you found this concept in the literature? Did those citations contain any further citations for this definition, and did you make any efforts to trace those citations back to find earlier sources for this idea?

Comment: Thanks, I'll improve it this way.